# Chrome downloads the HTML contents instead showing it

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, http-headers, content-type

One of the web application that we use opens fine in Internet explorer. But not on Chrome.

I have looked through the content of page and it has `meta` tag with `content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>COMPASS</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

<frameset rows="160,*" cols="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="NO" border="0">
  <frame src="banner/banner.htm" name="topFrame" scrolling="NO" noresize >
  <frame src="home.htm" name="mainFrame">
</frameset>
<noframes><body>

<a href="default.htm">default</a>
<a href="banner/banner.htm">banner</a>
</body></noframes>
</html>
```

So I looked through the HTTP headers, and it contains content-type as `application/octet-stream`. Full header list is shown below.

```
Accept-Ranges →bytes
Content-Length →613
Content-Location →http://myURL/Default.htm
Content-Type →application/octet-stream
Date →Wed, 04 May 2016 12:21:01 GMT
ETag →"1000558dca1:f35"
Last-Modified →Mon, 04 Jan 2010 15:45:54 GMT
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer →5.0_Pub
Server →Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
```

Now that being said, What should I do in my browser in order to view this page on Chrome?

NOTE: I do not have access to make changes to the server or the
webapps hosted on it.

Comment: Chances are the file has an `.html` extension, and the server is only configured properly for `.htm` files or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is sending back `Content-Type →application/octet-stream` in the response header. This mime type is used to send an unknown binary. It looks like the server is not set up to send the correct response header.

If you would like to modify the behaviour of your browser, so that you can view the response in the browser window instead, you could try this extension: [Modify Content-Type](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-content-type/jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka).

Comment: Thumbs up for both your answer and the extension link! *_^

Comment: works like a charm.. why didnt I looks for a extension already..? Thanks.